# How to make the toolbar appear when switching between fragments using CoordinatorLayout, Toolbar and fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'm using the layout below, The `CoordinatorLayout` holds inside it `AppBarLayout` (With Toolbar) and the `fragment` layout.

I'm using `app:layout_scrollFlags` in my Toolbar and `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in the fragment, so the Toolbar appear and disappear (hide/show) with scrolling my fragment content.

**My problem:** when I scroll in fragment A and therefore the toolbar disappear, then I use the `BottomNavigationView` to go to fragment B the toolbar remains hidden.
**I want the toolbar to appear every time I open new fragment**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/containerMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/AppBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_bar"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_color_nav"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_color_nav"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/main_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Note : this is my MainActivity Layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that the xml you posted is your layout for your MainActivity(), if so create a reference to your Toolbar in your MainActivty and create a function in your MainActivty() to access/change your Toolbar collapse states.

In your Fragments, create a reference to your MainActivity to then access the function to change the state of your Toolbar.

I cannot test as from work, but I have used same code flow to do the same stuff when using only MainActivity with Inner Fragments as the navigation flow of the app.

Below not exact working or tested code, but same idea/flow

```
//my fragment function to access MainActivity().changeToolbarState(boolean)
changeToolbar(state: boolean) {
    if(state){
      //true
      //show toolbar
      MainActivty().changeToolbarState(true)

    }else{
      //false
      //collapse/hidetoolbar
     MainActivty().changeToolbarState(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect ! I created a reference to my AppBarLayout in the MainActivity
and i used : appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);

Answer (score 1):

The best alternative could be enabling setExpanded property of app bar layout to true with the following code inside the fragment. Here, MainActivity.appBarLayout is the static variable defined in Main Activity referenced to App Bar Layout.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    MainActivity.appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);
}
```